# Global error handling with RxJavaErrorHandler

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2, reactivex, rx-java3

I have the below method which throws an exception and want to catch that exception on the global level

```
public Maybe<FindProductCommand> get(ProductSearchCriteriaCommand searchCriteria) {
        LOG.info("Controller --> Finding all the products");
        return iProductManager.find(searchCriteria);
    }
```

As per the reactivex documentation http://reactivex.io/documentation/plugins.html

To do this, extend the `class RxJavaErrorHandler` and override this method:

```
void handleError(Throwable e)
```

I am using micronaut application with java and have the below dependency

```
implementation("io.micronaut.rxjava3:micronaut-rxjava3")
```

And tried below code

```
public class RxJavaExceptionHandler extends RxJavaErrorHandler{
}
```

Cannot import RxJavaErrorHandler

While looking for the solution the below code is used in many examples

```
RxJavaPlugins.getInstance().registerErrorHandler(new RxJavaErrorHandler() {
        @Override
        public void handleError(Throwable e) {
            Timber.e(e.toString());
        }
    });
```

However, getInstance().registerErrorHandler is not found in RxJavaPlugins

Comment: Is it an option to use the dependency rxjava from the group-id "io.reactivex"?

Comment: Since I am using the micronaut framework, which has the dependency io.micronaut.rxjava3

Comment: That global hook is no longer available since RxJava 2. There is no replacement functionality; you'll have to put logging in all of your `onError` callbacks.